# 80s/90s film about creatures that come alive after midnight, hunting people who read a particular book

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was very little when I watched it, so I don’t remember the name or the actors in that film (80s to early 90s).

The story was about a Bo with scary stories/monster stories in it. Every time someone read from the book after midnight, exactly after 12 o'clock, the creatures come to life and hunt down the people who read from the book.

It was a pretty scary film.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a bit like the spoof film "Saturday the 14th" from 1981. I remember them opening up and reading a book and a bunch of monsters come out from it.  It was supposed to be a horror-comedy. But, depending on how young you were, I could see it being more on the horror side for you.

Per [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083033/):

> "Primarily a spoof of the *Friday the 13th* series, but also takes shots
>   at several other horror films. After his family moves to a new house,
>   a young boy discovers a mysterious book describing the curse hanging
>   over the date of Saturday the 14th. Opening the book releases a band
>   of monsters into the house, and the family must join together to save
>   themselves and their neighborhood. "

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday_the_14th) has a similar description:

> "Billy finds the mysterious book. He reads of a curse hanging over the
>   date of Saturday the 14th. As he turns the page, a monster is
>   unleashed, and with each turn another disappears from the page and is
>   materialized within or outside the home. The house is soon swarming
>   with monsters."